# What does disc sliding over a string means in this system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

I was studying Newton's Laws of Motion and my book gives a diagram in order to explain what components together can or cannot be considered a system in the figure given below.

[image]

Now it says we cannot consider D and E together as a system as they don't travel the same distance because the disc D slides over a string but I'm having a hard time getting how exactly is it sliding over the string. Is the string wound up on the disc?

Comment: *Maybe* it means the string slides over the disk. IDK but this is a  terrible diagram, as you can see the string coming off the lower pulley is definitely not in the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

It means the disk is not connected to the string and so the movement of the string doesn't affect the position of the disk and vice-versa. So, if the string is pulled, then the block E will be pulled along with it, but disk D doesn't change position. Therefore D and E cannot be taken as a single system.